# SharePoint Search Query by CreatedBy User Email instead of CreatedBy User Name

Tags: sharepoint-search

SharePoint is mixing up results when i use search query CreatedBy:{User.Name} for users with same name. Is there a way to query by user.email for createdby property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try one of the `OWSUSER` fields (depending on what you are trying to achieve. For example:
`EditorOWSUSER:{User.Email}` or `AuthorOWSUSER:{User.Email}`

Comment: Awesome! It worked thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, can you credit me the answer?